# How to Visualize Transfer Rate In TRAMP Mode File Transfer

Tags: tramp, ssh

Any idea on how could be enabled a progress bar and/or speed rate metter on TRAMP mode file transfer?

Trying to manage TRAMP transfer mode via `scp` instead of `ssh` to seek avoidance `base64` conversion, but due low internet speed don't know if it's stuck or just slow.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install `iftop` package, run a `M-x` `term`, then type something as:

`$ iftop -i eth0 -f 'dst host 192.168.1.3'`

As for:

`-i` local interface

`-f` filter code, as in [pcap-filter](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pcap-filter) man page, for destination host in the example.

There will be 3 speed rates in inferior right part of the screen, meaning that for 2, 10 and 40 seconds respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as of today. Patches welcome!

Comment: Please consider elaborating, to say how to submit a patch. Thx.

Comment: Patches can be submitted either directly to the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` mailing list, or reporting it as Emacs bug via `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Please put the info of your comment into the answer. Comments can be deleted at any time. Q & A should stand on their own. Thx.

Comment: Drew, sorry for my resistance: all of this this documented in the Tramp manual. Please don't be more pedantic than us Germans :-)